# Can someone please clarify the different sentence structures I can use "下去" in?

Tags: grammar

I thought that 下去 was generally used in a V+下去 format. For example: 活下去

But I'm seeing it used before a verb in this sentence?  "父亲接下去说:..."    And in this sentence: "你这样下去会累垮的。”

Why am I so confused? Help. Please.

p.s. I just realized I may actually be confused by 接 in this sentence... Possibly could someone explain it to me? :/

Comment: for use after verbs see grammars on （compound） directional complements (e.g. 接下去）, for 下去 as independent verb see dictionaries, e.g. bkrs:I
[go down; descend] 由高处到低处
月亮下去了

Answer (score 3):

have a look of the 國語辭典, "下去" has 4 meanings:

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000105631

1　自上而下 - from top to bottom

2　用在動詞後﹒強調由上向下之意 - used after a verb, emphasise the action from top to bottom

3　用在動詞後﹒表示事情繼續進行 - used after a verb, showing the continuous state of the action

4　用在形容詞後﹒表示程度漸漸增加 - used after adjective, indicate the degree is increasing

in the example, "接下去说" is equal to "接著说", #3

then, "你這樣下去會累垮的" is also #3

Answer (score 3):

The other answer already explained the different usages of 「下去」, 
I would look into the logic behind it, and illustrate it with some examples.

「下去」is basically [下- down / downward (adverb) + 去 (directional particle)] structure that modify a verb before it.

Example:

- 踢下去 kick down
- 咬下去 bite down
- 劈下去 hack down

In the three examples above, the role of 「下去 」is simple -  it  indicates which direction the verb apply to (*downward)

The other use of "V+下去" indicate continuation of an action 「下去」= ( down the order/ continue next)

Example:

- 讀下去 (keep on reading)
- 唱下去 (keep on singing)
- 想下去 (keep on thinking)

It functions like "繼續+V"

- 繼續讀(keep on reading)
- 繼續唱(keep on singing)
- 繼續想(keep on thinking)

> p.s. I just realized I may actually be confused by 接 in this sentence... Possibly could someone explain it to me? :/

接 here is a verb "to continue"

> "父亲**接 下去 *说:.."

"my father **continued, *and said:..."

- "and" in English also indicates "down the order in time line". For example:" catch and release" = "catch first then release right after"